# How to retrieve data from spreadsheet for chart google script. (Using HTML Service)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-apps

Hey good morning/afternoon/evening depending where you guys are at!

Just have a quick question for you guys. I've been stuck on this for a bit, and I've tried looking around, but i can't seem to find the answer for this specific issue.

So I'm in the process of trying to create a column chart using google scripts with the html service (since they UIApp service is depreciated now). I'm trying to retrieve the data from a spreadsheet have already created. But when i use this code, the page comes up blank as if there is some error in the background.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1gdRB6FFV426bAj95C0xJlqSucnnX0Z5ATVQdC2");
```

So here are some specifics:

1) I put this line in my Index.html file within a function I have called

```
drawChart();
```

2) I do have them wrapped in this tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

3) I know that this line of code is the cause of the issue because as soon as i comment it out my temp graph with temp data pops up, and page runs fine. But as soon as uncommented it blanks out the whole page.

Any ideas?

I'm wondering if I have to actually place this line of code within the "Code.gs" file, then some how transfer the data from Code.gs to my Index.html file. If that's the case can anyone point me in the direction to where I can follow the direction on how to do it?

Thank you guys in advance.

Sincerely,
Sicariuxs

Comment: If `SpreadsheetApp` is in an HTML script tag, it will not run.  `SpreadsheetApp` will only work in a `.gs` file.  It's not JavaScript, it's unique to Google Apps Script.

Comment: For an example of putting a chart into a stand alone Web App, see this shared Apps Script.   [Shared Apps Script File](https://script.google.com/d/1u2DwA7zDgltz5ZwvQ1Pxmxx161xU_rox1iJ_s7d-J7truWKszj6Zfqnq/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: Please help us help you. If the GAS script runs fine, the error is in the HTML somewhere - you can see it by checking your browser console. As Sandy said, it may very well be due to having that line of code in the JavaScript instead of a `.gs` file. Also note that you don't necessarily need `SpreadsheetApp`, you can use `google.visualization.Query` as well which can only be used in JavaScript. [details here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#Google_Spreadsheets_as_a_Data_Source)

Comment: Okay so the issues it that i have the error within my HTML tags because like @SandyGood said SpreadsheetApp will not run within HTML. So is it possible for me to write the SpreadsheetApp code in the .gs file and send the data to a variable within my HTML tags? or would I have to use "google.visualization.Query" as @ Adelin mentioned to gather all the data from a spreadsheet?

Comment: You need to take a look at the `google.script.run` client side API.  That's what is used to make calls the the server, and handle the returned data with a `withSuccessHandler()`.  [Link to 
Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a `withSuccessHandler(functionNameToReceiveData)`.

```
<script>
  function getData() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(functionNameToReceiveData)
      getData();
  };

  function functionNameToReceiveData(theDateReceivedHere) {
    Logger.log('theDateReceivedHere: ' + theDateReceivedHere;

  };
</script>
```

You can't use: `var data = google.script.run.getData();`  You must use a `withSuccessHandler(functionNameToReceiveData)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sandy Good . But i have the actual chart working. What i actually need is a way to receive the data from the Spreadsheet. Still trying out different things. But no success yet. Something i tried was was `var data = google.script.run.getData();` and in that function i had the data coming in from a spreadsheet. Which in the log it populates. but It doesn't seem to allow me to return the data back to `var data` located on the index.html file.

Comment: Okay so for my .gs file I have this [link](https://i.imgur.com/kTG43Nf.png)
And for my .html file I have this. [link](https://i.imgur.com/kTG43Nf.png)
It still does not work. But I have done some tests. I tried entering some hard coded data like this `dataTable.addRows([[new Date('2014-09-14'), 5093, 1613]]);` I then commented out "data" in my .html file. Still didn't work. Then in my .gs file I tried returning a different value instead of "data". So I wrote this instead. `return 1` and then it worked. So I came to the conclusion that for some reason I can't return "data". Ideas?

Comment: Also here are the errors i'm getting in the developer's console [link](https://i.imgur.com/PKmCUvQ.png) I have absolutely NO IDEA what that means. Which is weird because I am indeed getting the data before it returns as shown here [link](https://i.imgur.com/dbCnXdw.png) Thanks guys for your guys' help!

Comment: sorry that was the wrong link for the errors. this is the error I am getting [link](https://i.imgur.com/MFloMmw.png). If the returning data is not supported. how else do i send this data from my .gs file to my .html file?

Answer (score 0):

@Sandy Good

Hey man I want to thank you for all your help. you're answer was actually great. But there was an additional mistake on top of the ones that you corrected me on. In my actual spreadsheet I had it as a "Date" value. But the format was not matching the data type in my "dataTable". It's working now though. I made all the changes you told me, but in addition I changed the value type from "Date" to "Text". Then in my for loop I wrote a "new Date()" function using the text as the format, and that worked here is some screenshots to show my end result.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9K5W.png)

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkTFH.png)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and marking as correct answer.  I'm glad you got it working.  I don't know if you can edit my answer, but if you can, you could make updates.